lsqcurvefit using dynamic input data
I have input vector $\boldsymbol{u}$ and output vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ of length $N$, and I use $u_k,y_k$ to denote the $k$-th elements of $\boldsymbol{u}$ & $\boldsymbol{y}$ and $u_{k-1}$ as the $\{k-1\}$-th element of $\boldsymbol{u}$ and so on. The output at time k, $y_k$, ideally follows the equation: $y_k = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big) + p\Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big)^2 + q\Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big)^3 $. The value of M is fixed and is in the range of 50. The unknowns are the parameters $h_0,\dots,h_M, p, q$. Using the measured data samples of $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$, I would like to use "lsqcurvefit" in MATLAB to determine the unknown parameters. The values of $u_0,\dots,u_{-M+1}$ are assumed to be 0. I do not know how to write this dynamic model in "fun" for the lsqcurvefit in MATLAB.

Here's an example that I tested with Matlab R2023b that hopefully you can modify to meet your needs, or at least see how it works. Note that I have defined an anonymous function. I used the filter function which by default assumes that the signal values prior to the start of the vector are zero, as per your problem specification.
The following code has been revised to match the revised problem in the comment:
% define signals
N = 100;        % example signal length
u = rand(N,1);  % example input signal
y = u;          % example output signal

% initial guesses (be aware that non-linear least squares approaches are typically
% dependent on having good initial guesses, which the following clearly aren't)
M = 50;
h = zeros(M,1);
r = 0;
p = 0;
q = 0;

% fit
tmp = lsqcurvefit(@(h,u)filter(h(1:M),1,u).^(1:3)*h(M+1:end),[h;r;p;q],u,y);
h = tmp(1:M);
r = tmp(M+1);
p = tmp(M+2);
q = tmp(M+3);


Thank you for the solution, it works perfectly. I would like to modify the line of code defining tmp for the model: $y_k = r\Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big) + p\Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big)^2 + q\Big(\sum_{i=0}^M h_iu_{k-i} \Big)^3 $, where r is a factor scaling the linear terms. I tried to include this in fun and initial values, but I get error.

I have modified my example code to match your revised problem. Out of curiosity, if you can fit it in the comment space, how did you modify my code for this revised problem that resulted in the error?

I tried different things, that resulted in error, and I also tried the modification you provided. The identified solution tmp here is a zero vector. But the actual solution should be that tmp(1) = tmp(M+1) = 1 or an approximation. do you have an explanation for that? Thank you for your modified solution.

In my example code, yes the optimisation completely fails. The reason is the initial guesses at the optimal parameter values are terrible (I set them all to zero). The thing you'll find is that optimisation algorithms typically require a good initial guess, otherwise they will converge to a local rather than global optimum.

The following will be good initial guesses: h = filter(y,u,[1;zeros(M-1,1)]) and r = 1 because it computes the impulse response, h, given the input u and output y and then using that value for r maintains the proportionality.
